# Invalid field Status__c for AggregateResult using GROUP BY in SOQL

Tags: apex, soql, picklist

I want to count records based on different values provided to records using `Status__c` field. `Status__c` is a picklist field. For efficiency purpose, I want to run one query but get different result of counts of records based on `Status__c` field. So, I am using Query with GROUP BY. However, getting this error

> System.SObjectException: Invalid field Status__c for AggregateResult

Code

```java
public static List<AggregateResult> getEverythingUsingGroubBy(){
    List<AggregateResult> lstContact = new List<AggregateResult>();
    lstContact = [SELECT count(Id) recordCount FROM Partner_Task__c GROUP BY Status__c];
    for (AggregateResult ar : lstContact) {
        System.debug('Count of tasks are ' + ar.get('Status__c') +'is '+ ar.get('recordCount'));
    }
    return lstContact;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is you are using Status__c without fetching it from query.

change

```
 lstContact = [SELECT count(Id) recordCount FROM Partner_Task__c GROUP BY Status__c];
```

To:

```
 lstContact = [SELECT count(Id) recordCount,Status__c FROM Partner_Task__c GROUP BY Status__c];
```

Comment: thanks, it resolved my issue.